# ROS-I Computer - Recommended RT - Operating System

Tags: ros, realtime, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I found out there are three ways to send data to an industrial robot:

1. Point Streaming
2. Trajectory Streaming (like Point Streaming but with velocities added to the stream)
3. Trajectory Downloading

The third point as I understood needs collision detection already before downloading the trajectory. **So this is not ment for heterogenous environments?**

The first and the second points are quite equal i guess. ROS-I on my PC can do on-the-fly-visualization and collision detection in *realtime*.
**What operating System on my PC/Laptop is needed for being able to use the realtime capabilities of ROS-I? Especially the collision detection?**
Is RTAI necessary or strong enough? Or is there any recommended RT-upgrade to any specific linux system?

**What connection is needed?**
I guess Ethernet via TCP/IP won't do. Would EtherCAT be usable?

Regards

Edit: My Imagination of realtime is yet hard to explain. But to be not too specific, I would rather like to know how realtime ROS-I is. What update rates are possible with ROS-I?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198003/ros-i-computer---recommended-rt---operating-system/) by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-11-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is my understanding that to use ROS-I you don't need any realtime guarantees. From what I've heard, typical ROS-I applications don't exceed update rates of 50Hz. You should be able to deliver that with decent latencies with a stock Linux kernel.

Something that is not clear from the question is what realtime means for you. At some parts of the question it seems that "realtime" means an update frequency fast enough to allow online visualization, which is in the order of tens of Hz. You typically start requiring some form of realtime scheduling when you need determinism at update rates of hundreds of Hz (or more).

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosBort](https://answers.ros.org/users/20405/rosbort/) on 2014-11-25**:
That's some good information! Thank you! I am waiting a little more, may there are some more people who'd like to give me feedback, before closing this question.
I now added on my imagination of realtime by editing my Question in the last line.